# C# SendInput() always returns 0 in Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application, xinput

I have developed a simple Console application to poll an Xbox Controller using xinput.  I would like to use the values obtained from one of the thumbsticks to move the mouse.  I am able to get the x and y values from the thumbstick, but when I use those values to SendInput() (using the User32.dll), the mouse does not move and the return value is 0.

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx), "If the function returns zero, the input was already blocked by another thread."

How do I find the other thread that is blocking it?  It is just a simple Console Application (exe) started by Visual Studio that prints the x and y values to the screen and attempts to move the mouse.

```
long x = controller.x;  // values from the controller
long y = controller.y;  // these are checked and do contain numbers

INPUT mouseMoveInput =  new INPUT();
mouseMoveInput.type = 0; // mouse
mouseMoveInput.mi.dx = x;
mouseMoveInput.mi.dy = y;
mouseMoveInput.mi.mouseData = 0;
mouseMoveInput.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

var result = SendInput(1, ref mouseMoveInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT());
// result always returns 0
```

Am I missing something?  Should this work?

Here are declarations:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public long X;

        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public long Y;

        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public uint MouseData;

        [FieldOffset(20)]
        public uint Flags;

        [FieldOffset(24)]
        public uint Time;

        [FieldOffset(28)]
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct KEYBOARDINPUT
    {
        public ushort Vk;
        public ushort Scan;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint Msg;
        public ushort ParamL;
        public ushort ParamH;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct INPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint type;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public MOUSEINPUT mi;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public KEYBOARDINPUT ki;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }
```

UPDATE:  using `mouse-event` does work, but this function is deprecated.  Is there a problem with using it anyway since it works?

There is something odd I'm getting with the struct sizes:

Size of tagINPUT: 40
Size of mouseMoveInput: 40
Size of MOUSEINPUT: 32
Size of uint: 4

But if `tagINPUT` consists of `MOUSEINPUT` and `uint` then shouldn't it's size be 36?

Comment: How did you declare SendInput? From the docs it looks like the second parameter should either be a ref or an array and here it is being passed by value.

Comment: Question edited.  I was writing the code from memory.  The second parameter is indeed sent as `ref`.

Comment: You no longer have the friendly .NET wrappers that throw an exception for you when the function fails.  You have to take care of that yourself now.  Ensure that the [DllImport] declaration has SetLastError=true and throw a Win32Exception when it returns 0.  Now you know why it failed.

Comment: @HansPassant  Good tip.  Doing this, I get the message "The parameter is incorrect."  Not a very descriptive message.  Any ideas on what to check?  I have checked the size of `INPUT` and made sure that it matches the size of `mouseMoveInput` and it does.

Comment: That with about 97.31% certainty indicates that you got the pinvoke declarations wrong.  The INPUT structure declaration is not simple.  We can't see any of it, verify it with the declarations available at the pinvoke.net website.

Comment: I have added my structure declarations.  I've checked this multiple times with pinvoke.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Your code doesn't go with your declarations though. Make sure your code actually compiles with the structs you use? When I have to correct your typos and guess what you meant, I can't be sure that I'm looking at the same problem as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of `SendInput` should be a pointer to an array, not a ref parameter, and especially not a ref directly to the struct.

I would also use explicit layout only for the struct that actually needs it, and let the rest be sequential. It's easier.

This code works for me:

```
const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint SendInput(uint numberOfInputs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] INPUT[] inputs, int sizeOfInputStructure);

void Main()
{
    INPUT mouseMoveInput = new INPUT();
    mouseMoveInput.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    mouseMoveInput.mi.dx = 10;
    mouseMoveInput.mi.dy = 10;
    mouseMoveInput.mi.mouseData = 0;
    mouseMoveInput.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

    var result = SendInput(1, new INPUT[] { mouseMoveInput}, Marshal.SizeOf(mouseMoveInput));
    if(result == 0) {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    public ushort wVk;
    public ushort wScan;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
    public uint Msg;
    public ushort ParamL;
    public ushort ParamH;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct INPUT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint type;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}
```

Comment: This works for me.  You are right, I needed to change the second parameter.  There is a lot of information out there that shows `ref` to be the correct way to do it, but only the pointer to array works for me.  I appreciate the time you took to help.  Thank you!